# Ошибка - This package requires php ^7.3|^8.0 but your PHP version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: php, laravel, composer, хостинг

Когда заливаю сайт на хостинг и прописываю в ssh терминале composer install вылетает миллион одинаковых ошибок, говорящие о том, что моя версия php 7.1.33, а нужна минимум 7.3. Я создал файл в корне проекта .bash_profile. Прописал туда alias php='/opt/php74/bin/php'
alias php-cgi='/opt/php74/bin/php-cgi'.
Когда пишу php -v Пишет 7.4.
Когда пишу php-cgi -v Пишет 7.4.
Но композер так же не устанавливается по тем же причинам. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config php

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать composer таким образом:

```
/opt/php74/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer install
```

**UPD:**
Для того, чтобы определить где находится composer, можно ввести команду:

```
which composer
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).